# App Name Not Changing for iOS Localization

Tags: xcode, localization

I am dumbfounded as to why my icon/app name will not change on the iPhone home screen when I change languages in the settings.

I have the proper code in my French info.plist for example

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Your_Product_Name"; 
"CFBundleName" = "Your_Product_Name";
```

But it still won't change.

The only way I've been able to change it is under Build Settings -> Product Name. But that shows the same name across all languages.

Any idea how to get the proper name for the correct language? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're on the right way, but still missing a step before getting it working :)

You need to add a setting in your "app"-Info.plist:

[image: Application has localized display name]

Add the "Application has localized display name" setting and set it to `YES`.

Assuming you have created your InfoPlist.strings correctly (you should have one InfoPlist.strings in your fr.lproj directory, and another one in the en.lproj directory, each of them containing the appropriate `CFBundleName` and `CFBundleDisplayName` settings), your app name should now be translated according to the device's language settings.

You can also check this pretty good tutorial about iOS localization to get you started: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer solved your problem, don't hesitate to select it as the right answer :)

Comment: Fixed my opposite problem where it was showing $(PRODUCT_NAME) as our title when language was changed. Added it and set it to NO to fix.

Comment: @Romain the app name still does not change according to the selected app language